# Foregin key constraint error but shouldn't be occuring

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have a list table with 5 entries in it, the first column in the identity column (PK), within a parent table is a column that is related to this list table by ID (FK). I am using C# in a web app to run an ExecuteScalar with a stored procedure to insert the items into the parent table.

This is within a SQL database

LIST TABLE:

```
ID INT (PK),
SKILL_SET_NAME VARCHAR
```

PARENT TABLE:

```
ID INT,
SKILL_SET_ID INT (FK)
```

ITEMS WITHIN LIST TABLE:

```
1, SOMETHING
2, ANOTHER
3, ELSE
```

INSERT STATEMENT INTO PARENT TABLE

```
INSERT INTO PARENT TABLE
(ID, SKILL_SET_ID)
VALUES
([NUMBER], 1)
```

**ACTUAL CODE** (changed the ExecuteScalar to NonQuery, and the SkillSetID is the foreign key)

```
public static void SetRIPSSkillSetDetails(int HDR_ID, int SkillSetID, string SkillSetOptional, int SkillSetRating)
{
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

    al.Add(new DictionaryEntry("@HDR_ID", HDR_ID));
    al.Add(new DictionaryEntry("@SKILL_SET_ID", SkillSetID));
    al.Add(new DictionaryEntry("@SKILL_SET_OPTIONAL", SkillSetOptional));
    al.Add(new DictionaryEntry("@SKILL_SET_RATING", SkillSetRating));

    Core.RunNonQuery("web", "[IPAM_GLOBAL_INSERT_PARTICIPANT_RATING_DTL]", al);
```

When the code runs the ExecuteScalar I get the Foreign key constraint error, Please help

Comment: Can you run that insert directly on the SQL server?

Comment: Why ExecuteScalar? I think you mean ExecuteNonQuery?

Comment: Yes I sure can, that is why this has me scratching my head

Comment: I am using existing code from an old "programmer" that used to work here

Comment: PARENT TABLE is empty before this statement?

Comment: Yes and no, yes when the very first insert happens, then no afterwards

Comment: Are there any triggers associated with these tables?

Comment: There isn't maybe dbo.FOO and user.FOO perhaps?

Comment: Can you provide the actual C# code you are using to do this? Possible parameter problem?

Comment: No triggers and no other tables anywhere with the names of these tables

Comment: It is hard to guess whats happening without seeing all the code down to your SqlCommand. Have you inspected the SqlCommand right before it gets executed to verify that the parameter values match what you think you're doing? Could it be that you are not retrieving the values from the ArrayList in the same order they were added (e.g. using foreach), and the actual SP call is constructed as "EXEC xxx (x,x,x,x)" instead of using SqlParameters, possibly passing them in the wrong order? I'm reaching here, of course..

Comment: LOL I have checked all that, and when you pass in parameters to a stored procedure i didn't think that the order mattered (even though they are being passed in the correct order anyway)

Comment: Well, yeah, they don't really matter if you use SqlParameters, but one could, if they were a masochist, build the call as a string using `exec` and pass the parameters as a list in order, and then execute THAT instead of actually using SqlParameters. I've seen stranger things.

Comment: I've never come across a FK error that was incorrect. I think somewhere, something is being inserted out of order. It would help us if you posted the SQL queries this produces/makes.

Comment: @rlb.usa, my operating theory is not that FK error isn't correct, but that the value that is trying to be inserted isn't the value the OP thinks he's inserting. Though his last comment confirms he's looked at the call at the end of the line, so it remains a mystery.

Comment: @jamietre, exactly, I agree with you (and gave you an upvote).

Comment: You say that you can execute the insert statement on the database server and it works fine.  You also say that you've verified that the application is calling the stored procedure correctly, but is encountering an error.  You should, then, be able to reproduce the error by calling the stored procedure directly on the database server with the same parameters used by the application.  If you're able to reproduce, then the problem is most likely within the stored procedure.  Visual Studio can step through stored procedures in a SQL Server database, so that may help you.

Comment: is there any more information in the error message like the name of FK violated or possibly any of the values involved?

Comment: Come on, cough up the SP and Core.RunNonQuery.

Comment: Ok, I did some more digging and found out that it WAS my stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stored procedure was bombing out, someone said you can step through sql storec procedures from VS, how do I do that?